# How to get ImageButton width

Tags: java, android, parameters, width

How can I get the width of an ImageButton that is set in **XML** to 0 and has size from the weight?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fluido"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:tint="@color/icon"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fluido" />

        <......../>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I get this value that was automatically set by the **weight**?

As set in **XML** as **0**, if I do: `imageButton.getWidth();` or `imageButton.getLayoutParams().width();` both return 0 as in XML.

Comment: use `imageButton.getWidth();` but **after** the layout phase - you could use `ViewTreeObserver` for that

Comment: @pskink I did not understand, could you explain better?

Comment: so what is unclear after reading `ViewTreeObserver` official documentation?

Comment: This link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using below snippet:

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } 
        // Correct view dimensions are here:
        int width  = yourView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = yourView.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This still returns 0

Comment: I thing setting the android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of 0dp will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **addOnPreDrawListener**

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw()
    {
        if (view.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        // put your code here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button;
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

int buttonWidth = button.getWidth();

// Showing the Result
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+buttonWidth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

// Layout Image
[image]

// Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's giving 0 because you have to make sure that the integer in which you store width is not declared as final.

It should be not like this:
[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnkDZ.png)